# How to initiate nodejs file that contains oauth2 procedure and api calls by clicking a button in angular 2 template

Tags: node.js, angular2-forms

I'm very new to angular2/nodejs and am trying to take form data and push it to hubspot. I really need some help on this one and feel like i've tried everything. My code is below:

form.component.html

```
<div xmlns="">
   <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input
    type="email"
    id="email"
    class="form-control"
    name="email"
    ngModel
    required
    [pattern]="'^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$'"
    >
</div>
  <div class="row moveRight">
    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
  <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="firstname"
    class="form-control"
    name="firstname"
    ngModel
    required
    >
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row moveRight">
    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="lastname"
        class="form-control"
        name="lastname"
        ngModel
        required
        >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="startnode" type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid" (click)="form.js">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

form.js

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  url: 'https://app.hubspot.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT-ID&scope=forms%20automation&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/',
  method: 'POST',
  auth: {
user: 'username',
pass: 'Password'
  },
  form: {
'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  var json = JSON.parse(res.body);
  console.log ("Access Token:", json.access_token);
});

var request = require('request');

var accessToken = "ACCESS TOKEN";

request({
  url: 'https://api.someapi.com/blah/something',
  auth: {
'bearer': accessToken
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res.body);
});


//require Node modules

var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');

// build the data object

var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'email': req.body.email,
  'firstname': req.body.firstname,
  'lastname': req.body.lastname,
  'hs_context': JSON.stringify({
    "hutk": req.cookies.hubspotutk,
    "ipAddress": req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress,
    "pageUrl": "https://localhost:4200 ",
    "pageName": "Example Title"
  })
});

// set the post options, changing out the HUB ID and FORM GUID variables.

var options = {
  hostname: 'forms.hubspot.com',
  path: '/uploads/form/v2/GUID/CLIENT-ID',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
}

// set up the request

var request = https.request(options, function(response){
  console.log("Status: " + response.statusCode);
  console.log("Headers: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('Body: ' + chunk)
  });
});

request.on('error', function(e){
  console.log("Problem with request " + e.message)
});

// post the data

request.write(postData);
request.end();
```

So 4 things I need help with
1) Ensure I am connecting my form fields to the nodejs fields correctly
2) initialize all the nodejs code after clicking the submit button
3) validate the access_token that I return, I can use to complete the authorization process to continue to the API post call.
4) is my api post request correct.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If there is anyway I can just do this in angular2 that would be even better